# HTML5 pattern ORDER NUMBER

Tags: regex, html

Im trying to figure out a pattern for my html code, which should accept exactly 5 numbers in the first part and 2 letters the bottom part(ex. 12345AB), but I cant seem to quite figure it out.

```
    <form action="/action_page.php">
  Order nr: <input type="text" name="OrderNR" pattern="[1-9]{5}+[A-Za-z]{2}" title="5 numbers and 2 letter">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

thanks

Comment: remove the `+`, and perhaps add the zero in the first character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to remove this `+` character.

```
pattern="[0-9]{5}[A-Za-z]{2}"
```

Comment: ...and add zero to the first character class.